# Content Search web part is missing 2 post items

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, blog, content-search-web-part

In SharePoint 2013 on premises, I have added a Content Search Web Part that displays all the latest blogs.

The simple query:

```
contentclass:STS_ListItem_Posts and  -Title="Welcome to my blog!"
```

I am sorting the list based on the Published Date (Descending). However, there are two particular blog items that are not showing in the results. These two articles share one thing in common, the author. One of them includes a video while the other includes a png picture. The rest items of the same blog are displayed properly in the search results. Is there any way to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: Does both articles have published at least one major version? Are you able to find these articles in Search Service Application > Crawl Log > URL View?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, both of them are published (v1.0) and approved. They have also been crawled recently.

Answer (score 1):

These results would be treat as the duplicated results.

In SharePoint 2013, the default settings for the Content Search web part is to trim the duplicated results. The trim duplicate option is hidden and by default(TrimDuplicates:True). It dues to this duplicate results not visible in the results. To enable the duplicate result use need to follow the steps:

1. Export the Content Search web part from the SharePoint page.

   [image]
2. Open the exported web part in notepad and search for "TrimDuplicates".

   [image]
3. Change"TrimDuplicates" value to `false`.
4. Save the file and import it as a new web part to SharePoint.

Comment: The value is already false. Is there any idea why the posts aren't showing from this user?